# how to get number of row (where the record id standing)

Tags: mysql

Here is instalments table. I'd like to get where instalments.id 46 standing which is 3rd row.

Please make sure look at order number.

The first column is a value that result should return.

```
     |  id  | order_id |
------------------------
  1  |  23  | OOO12345 |
------------------------
  2  |  45  | OOO12345 |
------------------------
  3  |  46  | OOO12345 |
------------------------
  4  |  61  | OOO12345 |

------------------------
  1  |  62  | OOO12346 |
------------------------
  2  |  63  | OOO12346 |
------------------------
  3  |  64  | OOO12346 |
------------------------

instalments.id = 46  =>  3 
instalments.id = 63  =>  2


SELECT  wr.order_id, i1.previous_rows
        // other fields from other joined tables
FROM writers.work_records wr
LEFT JOIN writers.instalments i ON i.id = wr.instalment_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT(id) as previous_rows, order_id, id
     FROM instalments
) AS i1 ON i1.order_id = wr.order_id AND i1.id <= wr.instalment_id
WHERE 
    wr.order_id = '00012345'
    conditions
```

Any help please.

Comment: What does `get where instalments.id 46 standing` means ?

Comment: if (instalments.id = 46) result is 3

Comment: you're looking for a row number ?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  They have no built-in "row numbers".  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: What does the first column represent?

Comment: So you want order OBE12345 with row 3 (46) and OBE12346 with row 2? using what logic?  I see no logic which can derive both of these.  If you're after the 3rd record of every order based on the ID, that would be one thing, but that's not the case here.  So IMO the question is unclear and until it's clarified, no one can really help.

Comment: I think its better to maintain a column in your table for this purpose, instead of calculating each time

Comment: isn't the first column just a row_number partition by order with a order on ID?

Comment: @Fury- Is it ok for modifying the table structure?

Comment: What do you mean? this table has two fields only instalments.id, instalments.order_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your IDs are in order, you could select the number of rows which have an ID lower than or equal to the ID you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as previous_rows
FROM installments 
WHERE id <= 46
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff yup, that would do it.  I'll hide in the corner with my stupidity, once I've updated the answer

Comment: This is not what I am looking for

Comment: This won't work I have conditions that will say order_id=OOO12345 and instalment=46. Now in left join I have to check instalment with order_id = OOO12345 which number is it?

Comment: @Fury You can just add `AND order_id = 'OOO12345'` to the query to limit to a specific order

Comment: I think this will work. It is just causing an error to condition. give me 2 min plz

Comment: I'm sorry but ---- LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(id) as previous_rows, order_id, id
    FROM instalments 
    WHERE deleted = 0
    GROUP BY order_id
    Order BY id ASC
   ) AS b1 ON b1.order_id = wr.order_id AND b1.id <= wr.instalment_id  --- doesn't work it shows all the previous_rows = 3

Comment: @Fury I've rejected your edit as the ordering wasn't needed.  So long as the id is not randomly entered for any given order_id (so the first entry will not be 99 then the second entry 53, as arbitrary examples) then the id < x doesn't need an order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77897/discussion-between-fury-and-gabe3886).

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SET @rownum = 0;

SELECT id
FROM
  (SELECT id
   FROM instalments
   WHERE id = 46) rownum;
```

OR

```
SELECT id
FROM
  (SELECT id
   FROM instalments,
     (SELECT @rownum:=0) r) rownum
WHERE id = 46
```

Comment: This is a meaningless result.